# In-Memory Database for JSON with Nested Dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, json, redis, nosql

I'm trying to maintain a very volatile database in memory (disk would be too slow), always updating as I'm listening to hundreds of JSON websocket streams.

Currently I'm using redis, but it doesn't have dictionary support, just arrays. You can dump a JSON string to a redis db, but redis won't know it's JSON. So you can't access or change a certain key's value; you have to load the whole JSON string, edit it, then dump it back into redis. This of course is very slow, and I'd like to stop doing this.

There's a library called reJSON which allows redis to recognize JSON and edit JSON dictionaries, but I'd have to rewrite a lot of my code to use it. However, if I used reJSON, I could directly access and edit particular keys' values instead of loading and dumping the whole JSON string.

Currently what I'm doing is concatenating key names since they contain dictionaries. The problem here is when there's a dictionary within a dictionary; I'd have to concatenate a 2nd time, and this would produce a -ton- of keys. I don't think this is the optimal approach.

I was also recommended to use Redis commands and hashes instead of just storing JSON strings, but hashes don't seem to support dictionaries, just arrays.

As for the data itself, I'm listening to websocket streams where each update gives me data like this:
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=XRPBTC&interval=5m&limit=1

This is a "candle" for the trading market "XRPBTC", and the candle completes every "5 minutes". I want to keep create a new key every time the first element of that API data changes (meaning 5 minutes have passed and there's now a new candle. This value is a millisecond epoch). If it didn't change, the current candle isn't new, but other elements of the array changed, and these changes need to be made in the redis DB.

Let's say I got a websocket update where the 4th element of the array of the current candle changed. This is most likely to happen, as it is the "close", or current price of the market.

What I have right now is a key called `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE`. This key's value is a dictionary of dictionaries.
https://pastebin.com/rAYs0TaN

The "close" value in redis is here:
`candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE["1554792300000"]["close"]`

I want to edit the value in redis to be the one I got in the new websocket update. `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE` contains nested dictionaries, and is 0.1 megabytes. Currently I load `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE` from redis as JSON, update `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE["1554792300000"]["close"]` to whatever is in the websocket update, then dump it back to redis as JSON. As you can tell, this is a lot of handling of old, unnecessary data when I'm focusing on the newest key `1554792300000`.

My options seem to be:

A. Use reJSON

B. Keep using vanilla Redis, but concatenate key names again, creating tens of thousands of keys (`candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE_1554792300000`, `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE_1554792600000`, `candles_XRPBTC5MINUTE_1554792900000`, etc for `1MINUTE`, `3MINUTE`, `15MINUTE`, for hundreds of other markets)

C. Try to store the data I retrieve from the websockets as Redis hashes instead of JSON strings

What is the best option here, and why? Are there any other options?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but can you not just use a dictionary?

Comment: You can try the [redisjson](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redisjson) module.

Comment: I think you've pretty much summed up your options... I'd go with redisjson (author here) and try avoiding big de/serializations (i.e. don't do JSON.GET on the root of big documents).